# attribute 'fallthrough' cannot be applied in this context

Tags: c++, attributes, visual-studio-2017, c++17

I'm trying to use the c++17 `[[fallthrough]]` attribute in visual studio 2017:

```
Qt::ItemFlags flags = Qt::ItemIsSelectable;

switch (index.column())
{
case 0:
    flags |= Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable;
    break;
case 2:
    [[fallthrough]]
case 3:
    [[fallthrough]]
case 4:
    flags |= Qt::ItemIsEditable;
    break;
}
return flags;
```

but I get the compiler error:

> attribute 'fallthrough' cannot be applied in this context

This seems like the only context where you can use `[[fallthrough]]`... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This cryptic error is given because `[[fallthrough]]` attributes require a semicolon to terminate them. Rewriting the case statement as

```
case 2:
    [[fallthrough]];
case 3:
    [[fallthrough]];
// ...
```

resolves the error.

Comment: To add on, attributes need to be attached to *something*, whether it's a class, function, statement... The semicolon allows it to apply to the null statement.

Comment: c++ compilers and their weird error messages.